# Javascript blocked during file download

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

After a week of programming a website with users control for file download, I finally uploaded it to my web hosting just to find a problem with javascript.
With JQuery I set a click event with "on" function.

```
$("#ContenedorPV").on("click", "img", function () {});
```

This way, everytime I click a programatically appended image it opens a modal with a "download" hyperlink that when clicked, downloads a file.

```
<a id="BotonDescargar" href="" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-light btn-flat white-text" download>Descargar</a>
```

href is empty because I change it with JQuery this way.

```
$("#BotonDescargar").attr("href", "descargar.php?ID=" + ID_Actual);
```

This code changes the URL, appendind the correct ID, this is when problem happens. When I click the download link, file starts downloading as would but! javascript stops responding, if I click another image my modal doesn't show up, if I reload the webpage even the "Document.Ready" script will not work, same problem. Everything goes back to normal when download completes, I tried with a hidden iframe and same problem, is there a correct way to download files without blocking my javascript code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: Please post your full solution and console messages if any.

Comment: Ok I think I found the problem... PHP is blocked while downloading, I tried running a PHP test while donwloading and never loaded, I'm using Godaddy linux hosting if it helps, any idea why that happens? Edit: I'm using PHP sessions, maybe that's why is blocked ?

Comment: If you're using PHP, we'll need to see what you're attempting with that as well

Comment: Thank you, I found the problem, posting it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My site uses POST to retrieve data from PHP scripts, those scripts use the PHP sessions. My download script verifies with session if the user has rights to access the file, after you use the "session_start()" it will block access to session until script finishes, in this case, until download finishes. That's why when downloading big files, Javascript wasn't able to retrieve data, thus causing a block, to fix this I used the next code just before the "Readfile" code.

`session_write_close();`

This way, I manually close the session, freeing it and letting other scripts access the session data, thanks for your time mates!.